# Dropbox ransomware experience

Tags: file-encryption, ransomware, dropbox

How Dropbox handles ransomware issues? Can it effectively restore files encrypted by ransomware? The reason I am asking is because I am looking for a bullet-proof solution against ransomware and wondering about creating up-to-date backup on Dropbox. I am still exploring other options, however, not on corporate level but rather something smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropbox supports versioning, and the [page about this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/security/ransomware-recovery) says:

> If you have a Basic (free) or Plus account, you can restore a previous version of a file within 30 days of the change. If you have a Professional or Business account, you have 120 days.

So create a Dropbox account with enough storage, let it sync all your files, and keep it syncing all the time. If ransonmware strikes, reinstall your OS, install Dropbox and get the backed-up files. You will want to contact Dropbox support to do this, as they can rollback your account to a point in time before the files were encrypted.

If you want to build a solution yourself, you could get a computer and install [FreeNAS](https://www.freenas.org/download-freenas-release/) on it (or buy a preinstalled box), and use it to backup. There's a lot of Windows applications to backup things. So you don't depend on Dropbox and will not have to download hundreds of GBs of data if ransomware got your files.

Comment: Depending on how the NAS system is set up, you don't even need extra software, you can just use File History.